# can't understand the ruby code snippets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Excuse me for the noob question.I am a beginner in ruby and rails and I was Developing a wizard or multi-steps forms in Rails.I was following the article

https://medium.com/@nicolasblanco/developing-a-wizard-or-multi-steps-forms-in-rails-d2f3b7c692ce

```
  module Wizard
    module User
      STEPS = %w(step1 step2 step3 step4).freeze

      class Base
        include ActiveModel::Model
        attr_accessor :user

        delegate *::User.attribute_names.map { |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :user

        def initialize(user_attributes)
          @user = ::User.new(user_attributes)
        end
      end

      class Step1 < Base
        validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /@/ }
      end

      class Step2 < Step1
        validates :first_name, presence: true
        validates :last_name, presence: true
      end

      class Step3 < Step2
        validates :address_1, presence: true
        validates :zip_code, presence: true
        validates :city, presence: true
        validates :country, presence: true
      end

      class Step4 < Step3
        validates :phone_number, presence: true
      end
    endmodule Wizard
    module User
      STEPS = %w(step1 step2 step3 step4).freeze

      class Base
        include ActiveModel::Model
        attr_accessor :user

        delegate *::User.attribute_names.map { |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :user

        def initialize(user_attributes)
          @user = ::User.new(user_attributes)
        end
      end

      class Step1 < Base
        validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /@/ }
      end

      class Step2 < Step1
        validates :first_name, presence: true
        validates :last_name, presence: true
      end

      class Step3 < Step2
        validates :address_1, presence: true
        validates :zip_code, presence: true
        validates :city, presence: true
        validates :country, presence: true
      end

      class Step4 < Step3
        validates :phone_number, presence: true
      end
    end
  end
```

**1)** what does the below code snippet do?

```
     delegate *::User.attribute_names.map { |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :user
```

**2)** what does the below code snippet do?

```
    def initialize(user_attributes)
      @user = ::User.new(user_attributes)
    end
```

Any help is Highly Appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Question #1

Is too broad. So, I'll take a pass there.

#### Question #2: What Does This Do?

```
delegate *::User.attribute_names.map { |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :user
```

I'm going to do this using `Person` because that's what I have (not `User`) in my app.

So... The `::` indicates that the class (called a `Constant`) should be looked up in the global namespace. Which suggests that the snippet came from an engine (although, not necessarily).

```
::Person
```

`.attribute_names` generates an `array` of the field names from the `persons` table.

```
> ::Person.attribute_names

 => ["id", "first_name", "last_name", "date_of_birth", "created_at", "updated_at", "sex_id", "ethnicity_id"]
```

`.map{ |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }` generates an `array` of `arrays` where the content of each `array` will become a delegated `getter` and `setter`:

```
> ::Person.attribute_names.map{ |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }

 => [["id", "id="], ["first_name", "first_name="], ["last_name", "last_name="], ["date_of_birth", "date_of_birth="], ["created_at", "created_at="], ["updated_at", "updated_at="], ["sex_id", "sex_id="], ["ethnicity_id", "ethnicity_id="]]
```

But, we want an `array`, not an `array` of `arrays`.  So, `.flatten` does the job.

```
> ::Person.attribute_names.map{ |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten

 => ["id", "id=", "first_name", "first_name=", "last_name", "last_name=", "date_of_birth", "date_of_birth=", "created_at", "created_at=", "updated_at", "updated_at=", "sex_id", "sex_id=", "ethnicity_id", "ethnicity_id="]
```

Borrowing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893557/why-do-i-need-asterisk-before-an-array):

> The splat operator (that is, the *) turns what would otherwise be an array into a list for assignment

Essentially, every element in the array will become an argument for `delegate`.

[delegate](https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) tells the object where this line of code exists to pass the method call on to another object.

`to: :user` indicates which object to pass the method call onto. In this case, `:user` is a method call which presumably contains an instance of `::User`.

If you did this manually, it would look something like:

```
delegate  :id,
          :id=, 
          :first_name,
          :first_name=,
          ...,
          to: :person
```

#### Question #3: What Does This Do?

```
def initialize(user_attributes)
  @user = ::User.new(user_attributes)
end
```

Every `class constant` inherits from `Class` (the 'root' `class Constant`):

```
> class Foo; end
  => nil

> Foo.is_a?(Class)
 => true
```

Every `class Constant` inherits `initialize` as a private method from `Class`:

```
> Class.private_methods.include?(:initialize)
 => true
```

`initialize` is a method that is called when you call `new` on a `class Constant` (like `User.new` or `Foo.new` or whatever):

```
class Foo

private

  def initialize
    puts "initializing"
  end

end

> Foo.new
initializing
  => #<Foo:0x00000006fe5140>
```

`initialize` (as inherited from `Class`) accepts no arguments.

```
> Foo.new(:baz)
 ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

But, you can override this in any given class definition:

```
class Foo

  attr_accessor :bar

private

  def initialize(bar)
    puts "initializing"
    @bar = bar
  end

end
```

And now `Foo` will accept arguments to `new`:

```
> @foo = Foo.new(:baz)
initializing
 => #<Foo:0x00000006f64720 @bar=:baz> 

> @foo.bar
 => :baz
```

Which is what is going on here:

```
def initialize(user_attributes)
```

This line simply creates a new instance of `::User`, passing along the `user_attributes`, which is assigned to the instance variable `@user`:

```
@user = ::User.new(user_attributes)
```

Comment: Very nice explanation care to continue on #3? Also if we are nit picking (which apparently I am) `to: :user` technically indicates a method to delegate to where as `to: :@user` would be the direct access to the `Object` stored in the instance variable `@user`

Comment: I was going to add that `:user` is a method call which presumably contains an instance of `User` (which I believe is also what you are saying). Sound right? BTW, you already handled #3, no?

Comment: Yes I apologize for my, clearly, preemptive captious comment. Also I removed my comment in respect to your far more elaborate explanation so please feel free to proceed